# iOS project provisioning with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having a problem generating the .IPA file in xamarin forms from visual studio 2019, I am using windows and accessing the mac via remote, when I am going to compile in ad-hoc it presents me with the following error and I have done many Suggestions that I saw browsing the internet and I am not successful yet, the error is as follows.

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/execute-task/MovilCLA.iOS/dd46564002fPrepareResourceRules
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Users/mac1/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MovilCLA.iOS/dd4656467c6354a7ca2a39885a4f2a317db4a502a213cab64744707fc8655556/bin/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/MovilCLA.iOS.app/ResourceRules.plist".    MovilCLA.iOS

Comment: Maybe the Remote client "times out". Whenever I have a problem remote from pc, I go to mac. Get it to work first in VS Mac. Make sure Mac OS, XCode, and VS Mac are all up-to-date. Download the source code from your source repository (e.g. git) to the Mac, and build it there. Sometimes after an update to xcode, there can be a delay of several MINUTES on the first build you attempt - XCode must update something internally. Once it works on Mac, it should work remote from pc.